# BIOs (sort of) cannot find boot manager after upgrade from 14 to 16.04LTS (dual boot)

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, upgrade

There's a good reason for the (sort of) in the title so bare with me. I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14 to 16.04LTS using the software updater app. When my computer starts up, it boots directly into Windows whereas before, the Ubuntu boot manager would come up and ask which OS I wanted to boot into.

When you press F11 to enter BIOs, my motherboard let's you choose the boot device first, as seen in the screenshot below. "Enter Setup" would actually enter the BIOs settings.

[image]

If I boot with ubuntu(P1:Crucial_CT240M500SSD1), everything works fine and the Ubuntu manager shows up as before. This makes sense since Ubuntu is actually installed on my 240GB Crucial SSD. But I'm not sure why the ubuntu(P3: WDC ...) option is there.

The problem is when I go into BIOs to try to change the boot device permanently, ubuntu(P1:Crucial_CT240M500SSD1) doesn't show up as seen below. This is really odd considering it showed up in the previous menu (previous screenshot).

[image]

I've tried booting using the "Hard Disk: Crucial_CT240..." option but I get an error message saying it's not a valid boot device. I'd prefer not to press F11 everytime I want to boot into Ubuntu, any thoughts?

Comment: First thought: You have UEFI, not BIOS, and you don't quite understand the differences. Start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Now, I don't know how the non-working entry got there but usually running `sudo update-grub` is enough to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sudo update-grub didn't seem to work though.